# Defining a global variable linked to a directory on an external server

Tags: bash

I am trying to use a set of routines in a particular software program, but the routines require a particular version of the software to run effectively (the version on my system is older than what is required). I can SSH into an external server which harbours a more current version. However, I have no idea how I can attach the location of the current software on the external server to the global variable that is supposedly on my system. Is it possible?

The form of the bash script that runs the routines is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script sets up the  IDL_PATH and IDL_STARTUP for gbtidl
# It then invokes idl via this path - be sure and edit this to
# reflect your local IDL installation.
LOCAL_IDL=/usr/local/bin/idl

# set the below env variable to the location of this installation 
export GBT_IDL_DIR=/home/rloughnane/gbtidl
```

I would like to edit the LOCAL_IDL variable name so that it points, if that is possible, to a file located on an external server.

Comment: Do you just need the *output* of the program, or does the program need to modify things on your computer?  If the latter, then you're out of luck.  If the former, then it may be possible to hack together what you need.  Alternatively, why can't you just log in to the remote host and run your script there?

Comment: Good point. However, it seems I have reduced privileges there. I will try and run the script on the server.